# "Accountability over" or "accountability for"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, nouns, prepositions

I want to talk about "teacher accountability __ their work within the classroom". I'm not sure which preposition follows *accountability*, *for* or *over*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

One is held accountable ***for*** something or other, not *over* it.  Someone can also be accountable ***to*** someone else for something.